# what is the meaning about s_i = s[i] - 'a'?

Tags: c++

```
void main()
{
string s, Letter;
cin >> s;
int count[26], i, s_i; 
for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    count[i] = 0;
int n = sizeof(s);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    s_i = s[i] - 'a';
    count[s_i]++; 
}
for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    if (count[i] != 0)
    {
        Letter = 'a' + i;
        cout << Letter << " : " << count[i] << endl;
    }
}
}
```

This is a program to count the number of letters of string.
What is the meaning about s_i = s[i] - 'a' ? Especially, why use - 'a'? Is there any other method to count letter?

Comment: Think about what `'a' - 'a'` would mean. Then what `'b' - 'a'` would mean.

Comment: 'a' + 1 = 'b', 'a' + 2 = 'c'

Comment: s_i = s[i] - 'a'. This is used for getting index from 0. Here simply you are taking difference of ASCII values of two characters.
Suppose s[i] ='b' 
then s_i = s[i] - 'a' means s_i = 98 (ascii value of char 'b') - 97 (ascii value of char 'a') = 1

Comment: Also please don't use `void main()`.

Comment: With this code you are likely to access beyond the bound of the `int bound[26]` array or get a negative index if the ASCII code of any letter in string is >`'z'` or is in upper case.

Comment: Unrelated to you question,`int n = sizeof(s);` will not give you the number of elements in the string, `s` is an `std::string` you need to use `s.size()` or `s.length()` to get the number of elements in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `x - 'a'` gives you the distance between the character value in `x` and the first lowercase letter of the alphabet.

For example:
'b' - 'a' == 1
'c' - 'a' == 2

**Edit 1: an easier method**
Declare your array of counts to have 256 slots.
Use the character as an index into the array.
Increment the value at the index.

For example:

```
unsigned int counts[256];
char c = 'b';
//...
counts[c] += 1;
```

Using the subtraction, `x - 'a'` allows for a smaller size array.

**Edit 2: More portable solution**
A more portable solution, one that doesn't depend on the encoding, is to use an array of characters containing the alphabet.  Search for the character, if found, the index is the characters' offset.

```
char c = 'j';
const std::string lowercase_alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
const std::string uppercase_alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
unsigned int counts[26] = {0};
//...
unsigned int index = lowercase_alphabet.find(c);
if (index != std::string::npos)
{
    ++counts[index];
}
else
{
  index = uppercase_alphabet.find(c);
  if (index != std::string::npos)
  {
    ++counts[index];
  }
}
```

The same concept can be applied to character arrays instead of the `std::string` type.

*Note:  The `toupper` and `tolower` functions are not used to avoid the localization overhead.*

Comment: You mean 26 slots, not 256?

Comment: To be pedantic, `'c' - 'a' == 2`, etc, is not guaranteed to be true, for example with [EBCDIC](http://www.csgnetwork.com/ascebcdic.html); the C standard only guarantees, IIRC, that 'a' < 'b' < 'c' < ...

Comment: @CinCout: No, the array is 256 slots, the range of a `char` type.  The method is easy because it requires no subtraction.  Use the character variable as an index into the array.

Answer (score 0):

Few point to note:

1. The program assumes string contains only LowerCase letters(a-z) and nothing else. Thus, there can be at maximum `26 possible character` from `[a-z]`
2. By doing `-'a'`, we are simply subtracting ascii value of `'a'` from the `s[i]`. Each characters has a unique [ascii value](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=19&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjc3OSRvtbMAhXLqY8KHXCZDd0QFghqMBI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FASCII&usg=AFQjCNFSokt7M__Fqagb0Pu_skP7NDsFfA&sig2=W7DyFNk5L7sJnG2_Y2IYbw). During the compilation, compiler checks for the the ascii value of `'a'` and replaces `-'a'` with `-48`. Instead of doing `-'a'`, we could have done `-48`, but in this case, we don't need to remember ascii value of `'a'` .
3. All the ascii values of `[a-z]` are continuous. `a's`  value being 48 and `z's` value being 57. Thus, by doing `s[i]-'a'`, we get to know what is the difference of `ith varaible` from `a`.
4. In the end `Letter = 'a' + i;` is done to get the original character.